# How to enable an "allow-insecure-localhost" flag in Chrome from selenium?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless

I want to enable "allow-insecure-localhost" flag from selenium.
How I can do it?

selenium: 3.12.0,   Python:3.6.5

Chrome driver creation code:

```
def create_driver():
    options = Options()
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.add_argument('allow-insecure-localhost') # I tried to be enable, but it does not affect to chrome.
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        chromedriver_path = r".\chromedriver"
    else:
        chromedriver_path = "../chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, chrome_options=options)
    return driver
```

Comment: try it `--allow-insecure-localhost`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. As per  the documentation [**`--allow-insecure-localhost`**](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-insecure-localhost) should be precceded by `--` as follows:

```
options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
```

> **`--allow-insecure-localhost`** : Enables TLS/SSL errors on localhost to be ignored (no interstitial, no blocking of requests)